# Django Restframework has_object_permission() function is not working for object permission

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of debugging my custom permissions class and returning a value of False for my has_object_permission() function, but my I'm still able to access my API (GET request), via Restframework's API browser without authenticating and I can't understand why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please see code below. for whatever reasons, it appears that my has_object_permission function is not executing.  Please Help

urls.py

```
router = BulkRouter()
router.register(r'api1', SimpleViewSet1)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/', include(router.urls, namespace='api1')),
]
```

views.py

```
class SimpleViewSet1(generics.BulkModelViewSet):    
    queryset = Barcode.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (MyUserPermission,)
    serializer_class = SimpleSerializer1


    def get_queryset(self):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=2)
        return Barcode.objects.filter(owner = user)


    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset())
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

permissions.py

```
class MyUserPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True


    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
```

serializer.py

```
class SimpleSerializer1(BulkSerializerMixin,  # only required in DRF3
                       ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta(object):
        model = Barcode
        # only required in DRF3
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
        fields = ('barcode_number', 'barcode_type', 'owner')
```

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Barcode(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'barcodes')
    barcode_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    barcode_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.barcode_number
```

Answer (score 1):

[Django Rest API Guide says](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions):

> Also note that the generic views will only check the object-level permissions for views that retrieve a single model instance. If you require object-level filtering of list views, you'll need to filter the queryset separately. See the [filtering documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) for more details.

rest_framework.generics.BulkModelViewSet, as it's name suggests,does bulk operations. It means that you have to use object-level filtering as proposed in the docs.

You should be looking especially under [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangoobjectpermissionsfilter) section. Pay close attention to the example and make use of the code. You should also read about the [DjangoModelPermissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions) to understand how does the example in the link above works.